# Convert multiple columns from numeric to factor

Tags: r, type-conversion

I thought this task is simple, then I was surprised that it wasn't.

I have multiple selected columns with coded responses (likert-scales). I want to transform them into a factor variable with factor levels (some of them were never chosen). The questionnair is in German, that is why I you probably won't be able to understand the labels.

```
df[,c(3:21,23:25)] <- apply(df[,c(3:21,23:25)],2,
                                       function (x) factor(x,
                                                           levels = c(0,1,2,3,4),
                                                           labels = c("gar nicht",
                                                                      "gering",
                                                                      "eher schwach",
                                                                      "eher stark",
                                                                      "sehr stark"))) 
df[,22] <- apply(df[,22],1,
                            function (x) factor(x,
                                                levels = c(0,1,2,3),
                                                labels = c("gar nicht",
                                                           "sofort",
                                                           "mittelfristig",
                                                           "langfristig")))
```

I will need to split those data frames because of the different scales. Nevertheless,
it does not transform my data accurately. The outcome is a character.

Here is my test data:

```
structure(list(ï..lfdNr = 1:20, company = c("Nationalpark Thayathal", 
"Naturpark Heidenreichsteiner Moor", "Naturpark Hohe Wand", "Tierpark Stadt Haag", 
"Ã–tscher TropfsteinhÃ¶hle", "Carnuntum", "Stift Heiligenkreuz", 
"Ruine Kollmitz", "Schlosshof", "Retzer Erlebniskeller", "LOISIUM Weinwelt", 
"Bio Imkerei StÃ¶gerer", "Amethyst Welt Maissau", "Donau NiederÃ¶sterreich tourismus", 
"NiederÃ¶sterreich Bahnen", "Benediktinerstift Melk", "Kunstmeile Krems", 
"Die Garten Tulln", "Winzer Krems ", "DomÃ¤ne Wachau"), A2_1_hitz = c(4L, 
NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 3L), A2_2_trock = c(3L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 
NA, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L), A2_3_reg = c(2L, 
NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 2L), A2_4_schnee = c(4L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 
3L, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L), B1_1_hitz = c(4L, 
NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 0L, 2L), B1_2_trock = c(3L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 
NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L), B1_3_reg = c(2L, 
NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L), B1_4_schnee = c(1L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L), B2_1_nZuk = c(3L, 
NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 
2L, 0L, 0L), B2_2_mZuk = c(3L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 2L, 
NA, 2L, NA, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 0L), B2_3_fZuk = c(3L, 
NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 
NA, 3L, 0L), C1_1_aktEin = c(2L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L), C1_2_zukEin = c(3L, 
NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 3L), C2_1_bisVer = c(2L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L), C2_2_zukVer = c(3L, 
NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L), C3_1_bisVer = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 
3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L), C3_2_zukVer = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
NA, 3L, 2L), C4_1_EinKlim = c(NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 0L, 1L, NA, 3L, 1L), D1a_1_StÃ.rke = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), D1b_1_Dring = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), D5_1_bestBed = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, 
NA, 3L, 3L), E1_1_zuBesuch = c(NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 1L, 4L, NA, 4L, NA), E1_2_wirtBed = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
NA, 3L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks,
nadine

Comment: You already got a great answer. In addition, yourself a favor and make the effort to index names instead of numbers `dat[c("A2_1_hitz", "A2_2_trock", ... "D1a_1_StÃ.rke")]`. You would never remember what the numbers mean otherwise, and the slightest change would mess up your setup. Try `names(dat)[c(3:21)] |> dput()` to not have to type anything.

Comment: Hi jay.sf thanks, that is a great hint! I wonder why I never thought about that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `lapply` and not `apply` as `apply` converts to `matrix` and matrix can have only a single class

```
df[,c(3:21,23:25)] <- lapply(df[,c(3:21,23:25)],
                            function (x) factor(x,
                                                levels = c(0,1,2,3),
                                                labels = c("gar nicht",
                                                           "sofort",
                                                           "mittelfristig",
                                                           "langfristig")))
```

Comment: I need to apply "lapply" because we have a data frame not a matrix? Or why is it impossible to convert the data type columnwise? Sometimes I confuse them.

Comment: @NadiineElNino You can use `apply` on both data.frame and matrix, where as `lapply` is used in `data.frame` or `list` as `data.frame` is a `list` with columns as vectors of equal length whereas matrix is a vector with dim attributes.  Thus, if you use `lapply` on matrix, it will loop over each element of the matrix instead of each column (as in data.frame).  Regarding the issue with `apply`, it depends on the function you want to apply.  If you want to do some transformation i.e. if all the columns are numeric and want to do some arithmetic, either apply or lapply can be used,

Comment: @NadiineElNino Here, you are converting columns to factor and as `apply` returns output in  a matrix, matrix cannot have more than one class..  factor is an evolved class with storage mode in integer, thus it is better to do this in lapply